# Python Scraper is only sending last URL in range to CSV writer

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

So my scraper is only sending the last URL in a range back to the CSV writer.
I cannot figure out where i'm missing the error. Hoping a fresh set of eyes may be able to help.

Code Below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

urls = ["https://www.realestate.com.au/property/1-125-mansfield-st-berwick-vic-3806",
"https://www.realestate.com.au/property/1-13-park-ave-mosman-nsw-2088",
"https://www.realestate.com.au/property/1-17-sarton-rd-clayton-vic-3168",
"https://www.realestate.com.au/property/1-2-bridge-st-northcote-vic-3070",
"https://www.realestate.com.au/property/1-2-marara-rd-caulfield-south-vic-3162",]
results = {}
for url in urls:
    resp = requests.get(url)
    if resp.status_code != 200:
        print('Failed in url {}'.format(url))
        continue
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html')
    link = soup.find(name='a', attrs={'class': lambda x: x and 'property-value__btn-listing' in x}) # find just takes the first one, so no repeated links
    href = link.get('href')
    results[url] = href
print href
```

Comment: indent your code. without indenting python code is meaningless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indent the `print href`.
If it is not in the loop, it will not be printed for all the urls. The last value of `href` will be printed. Hope this helps!

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much !